# istream_iterator: taking extra input

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, istream

I can't get this blasted thing working right. The problem is, If I want to enter 2 numbers, I actually have to enter 3. What is wrong?

```
namespace MT
{
    template<class IIT, class OIT>
    OIT copy_n(IIT iitBegin, size_t szCount, OIT oitBegin)
    {   
        for(size_t szI = 0; (szI < szCount); ++szI)
        {   
            *oitBegin++ = *iitBegin++;
        }   

        return oitBegin;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> vNumbers;
    vector<char> vOperators;
    int iNumCount = 0;
    int iNumOperators = 0;

    cout << "Enter number of number(s) :) :\n";
    cin >> iNumCount;
    cout << "Enter number of operator(s) :\n";
    cin >> iNumOperators;

    int iNumber;
    cout << "Enter the " << iNumCount << " number(s):\n";
    MT::copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin), iNumCount, back_inserter(vNumbers));

    char cOperator;
    cout << "\nEnter the " << iNumOperators << " operator(s):\n";
    MT::copy_n(istream_iterator<char>(cin), iNumOperators, back_inserter(vOperators));

    copy(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    copy(vOperators.begin(), vOperators.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated (probably) issue:  your second istream_iterator<int> should be istream_iterator<char>.  Same with the second ostream_iterator<int>.  Those are going off of a vector<char>.

Comment: @luke : Yes, edited. Problem remains.

Comment: You have a couple of stream extraction lines there: `cin >> iNumCount` and `cin >> iNumOperators`. I presume you don't count them when you say you need to enter 3 values when you "want to enter 2"?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I'm talking about after that. After I get those, suppose `iNumCount` is 2. Then I expect the input reading to be over when I enter 2 numbers. This does not happen. I have to enter 3.

Comment: Advice:  Don't use post-increment, it spawns an unnamed temporary almost every time, and its definitely the case when what you're incrementing is a stream iterator.  `*oitBegin = *iitBegin; ++oitBegin; ++iitBegin;`  This may even be the cause of your bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your stream iterator loop to:

```
    for(size_t szI = 0; (szI < szCount); ++szI)
    {   
        *oitBegin = *iitBegin;
        if (szI < szCount - 1)
        {
          ++oitBegin;
          ++iitBegin;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works. And `copy` returns the output iterator to the last element inserted. So I think it is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `istream_iterator` reads not when it's dereferenced, but when it's incremented :

- A first value is read when the `istream_iterator` is constructed
- iNumCount additional values are read by copy_n when the iterator is incremented

In other words, you have one too many `iiBegin++` which reads a value that gets discarded. On any *classic* iterator, this last increment would get you 'past the end', but here it triggers an unwanted read from the standard input (which obviously doesn't have an end).

**[EDIT]** Possible solution :

```
template<class IIT, class OIT>
OIT copy_n(IIT iitBegin, size_t szCount, OIT oitBegin)
{   
  *oitBegin++ = *iitBegin;
  for(size_t szI = 0; (szI < szCount - 1); ++szI)
    *oitBegin++ = *++iitBegin;
  return oitBegin;
}
```

Comment: OK. So, how do I keep `copy_n` generic and use an `istream_iterator` with it and make it behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not passing the EOF symbol. If you are working under Linux, try to type CTRL+D after inserting the second number (under Windows should be CTRL+Z but I'm not sure).

Comment: `copy_n()` should assume a valid range of at least `n` elements. It should stop after iterating over `n` elements. The algorithm shouldn't reach the end position.